# How to check max difference in dates between events and create new column in SAS Enterprise Guide?

Tags: date, sas, proc-sql, enterprise-guide, 4gl

I have table in SAS Enterprise Guide like below.

Data types and meaning:

- ID - numeric - ID of client
- DT - date - date of change
- OFFER_1 - charcter - current offer
- OFFER_2 - character - offer after change

**Values in original dataset are not sorted, but it can be sorted if it is important for solution.**

```
ID   | DT        | OFFER_1  | OFFER_2
-----|-----------|----------|----------
123  | 01MAY2020 | PR       | PR
123  | 05MAY2020 | PR       | P
123  | 10MAY2020 | P        | P
123  | 11MAY2020 | P        | P
123  | 20MAY2020 | P        | PR
123  | 21MAY2020 | PR       | M
123  | 25MAY2020 | M        | M
777  | 30MAY2020 | PR       | M
223  | 02JAN2020 | PR       | PR
223  | 15MAR2020 | PR       | PR
402  | 20MAR2020 | M        | M
33   | 11AUG2020 | M        | PR
11   | 20JAN2020 | PR       | M
11   | 05FEB2020 | M        | M
```

And I need to create new column "COL1" where will be information:

- If client change offer from PR to P or M then count how many maximum days he lasted before returning to PR again, or how many days he is already on P or M after the change, if he has not returned to PR
- If he did not change PR to P or M "COL1" = 0

So, as a result I need something like below:

```
ID   | DT        | OFFER_1  | OFFER_2  | COL1
-----|-----------|----------|----------|---------
123  | 01MAY2020 | PR       | PR       | 15
123  | 05MAY2020 | PR       | P        | 15
123  | 10MAY2020 | P        | P        | 15
123  | 11MAY2020 | P        | P        | 15
123  | 20MAY2020 | P        | PR       | 15
123  | 21MAY2020 | PR       | M        | 15
123  | 25MAY2020 | M        | M        | 15
777  | 30MAY2020 | PR       | M        | 1
223  | 02JAN2020 | PR       | PR       | 0
223  | 15MAR2020 | PR       | PR       | 0
402  | 20MAR2020 | M        | M        | 0
33   | 11AUG2020 | M        | PR       | 0
11   | 20JAN2020 | PR       | M        | 16
11   | 05FEB2020 | M        | M        | 16
```

Because:

- ID = 123, has 15 in "COL1" - because changed PR to P or M and lasted a maximum of 15 days (from 05MAY2020 till 20MAY2020) before return to PR again, changed PR to P or M 2 times but the 2nd time the change lasted 4 days and 15 > 4
- ID = 777, has 1 in "COL1" - because changed PR to P or M and lasted a maximum of 1 day (30MAY2020)
- ID = 223, has 0 in "COL1" - because he did not change PR to P or M
- ID = 402, has 0 in "COL1" - because he did not change PR to P or M
- ID = 33, has 0 in "COL1" - because he did not change PR to P or M
- ID = 11, has 16 in "COL1" - because changed PR to P or M and lasted a maximum of 16 days (from 20JAN2020 till 05FEB2020) and did not return to PR again

@Stu Sztukowski - Below exaplmes from my real data where your code does not work. I add also how it should be :)

**Examples where code works wrong**:

| ID | DT | OFFER_1 | OFFER_2 | COL1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1020 | 01SEP2020 | P | P | 1 -> number of days between 01SEP2020 and 02SEP2020 but there was not changes from PR to P or M, so this client does not interes for us, it should be 0 |
| 1020 | 02SEP2020 | P | P | 1 |
| 2030 | 29JUL2022 | P | P | 50 -> number of days between 20JUL2022 and 17SEP2022 but there was not changes from PR to P or M, so this client does not interes for us, it should be 0 |
| 2030 | 15JUL2022 | P | P | 50 |
| 2030 | 17SEP2022 | P | P | 50 |

**How it should be:**
Because only change from PR to P or M are interested for us, example at the bottom of this post presents it. Below examples are similar like my examples ID = 223 or 402 from the bottom of this post :)

| ID | DT | OFFER_1 | OFFER_2 | COL1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1020 | 01SEP2020 | P | P | 0 |
| 1020 | 02SEP2020 | P | P | 0 |
| 2030 | 29JUL2022 | P | P | 0 |
| 2030 | 15JUL2022 | P | P | 0 |
| 2030 | 17SEP2022 | P | P | 0 |

How can I do that in SAS Enterprise Guide in PROC SQL or in normal SAS code ?

Comment: You say that the data is not sorted. But it seems to be at least grouped by ID and sorted by dt within each ID, correct?

Comment: Peter, This is the case in my example, in my real data the values are sorted neither by ID nor by DT :) But of course, you can sort it if it is important for your solution :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `offer_1` is `P` or `M`, then we just need to take the difference between the current date and the previous date. We'll use some rules to calculate the differences based on your rules. From there we can join the max values back with the original data.

```
proc sort data=have;
    by id dt;
run;

data date_difs;
    set have;
    by id dt;
    retain flag_pr_pm start_dt;

    if(first.id) then call missing(flag_pr_pm, start_dt);

    if(offer_1 = 'PR' AND offer_2 IN('P', 'M') ) then do;
        flag_pr_pm = 1;
        start_dt   = dt;
    end;

    if(   (offer_1 IN('P', 'M') AND offer_2 = 'PR')
       OR (flag_pr_pm AND last.id AND NOT first.id)
      ) 
    then do;
        flag_pr_pm  = 0;
        total_days = dt - start_dt;
    end;

    if(    first.id 
       AND last.id 
       AND offer_1 = 'PR' 
       AND offer_2 IN ('P', 'M')
      ) 
    then total_days = 1;

    format start_dt date9.;
run;
```

Which gets you:

```
id    dt         offer_1    offer_2   flag_pr_pm    start_dt    total_days
11    20JAN2020  PR         M         1             20JAN2020   .
11    05FEB2020  M          M         0             20JAN2020   16
33    11AUG2020  M          PR        0             .           .
123   01MAY2020  PR         PR        .             .           .
123   05MAY2020  PR         P         1             05MAY2020   .
123   10MAY2020  P          P         1             05MAY2020   .
123   11MAY2020  P          P         1             05MAY2020   .
123   20MAY2020  P          PR        0             05MAY2020   15
123   21MAY2020  PR         M         1             21MAY2020   .
123   25MAY2020  M          M         0             21MAY2020   4
223   02JAN2020  PR         PR        .             .           .
223   15MAR2020  PR         PR        .             .           .
402   20MAR2020  M          M         .             .           .
777   30MAY2020  PR         M         1             30MAY2020   1
1020  01SEP2020  P          P         .             .           .
1020  02SEP2020  P          P         .             .           .
2030  15JUL2022  P          P         .             .           .
2030  29JUL2022  P          P         .             .           .
2030  17SEP2022  P          P         .             .           .
```

Now join the max value by ID back to the original data:

```
proc sql;
    create table want as
        select *, col1
        from have as t1
        LEFT JOIN
             (select id, max(total_days) as col1
              from date_difs
              group by id
             ) as t2
        ON t1.id = t2.id
    ;
quit;
```

This gives you the exact solution within your sample data.

Comment: Stu Sztukowski: " take the difference between the current date and the previous date" it is not good - I modify example for ID = 123, as you can see there was change from PR to P in 15MAY2022 then was not change 18MAY2022 and then there was change back from P to PR in 20MAY2022, so you can not calculate difference between 20MAY2022 and 18MAY2022, it should be difference 20MAY2022 and 15MAY2022 :) can you change code ?

Comment: you have to calculate difference between day when was change from PR to P or M to the day when was change back from P or M to PR - it there was such change, please change you solution :)

Comment: Stu Sztukowski, your solution is wrong, could you repair that, please ?

Comment: @unbik the solution has been changed. Please note that tagging me and posting multiple times is not going to get me to respond faster. I can appreciate your sense of urgency, but I am volunteering to help you and will respond when I have time. In the meantime, please study the SAS language basics so you can modify and answer your own questions in case someone else cannot help you.

Comment: Stu Sztukowski, almost right but not quite. because using your modified code when I have offer_1 = P or M and offer_2 = P or M I should have 0 or NaN,
but now you count difference between the first and last DT of such an ID. 
We are only interested in the maximum number of days the customer has endured after changing from PR to P or M if he has made several such changes,
 or simply the number of days how many he is already on such a change. 
If he changed P to P or M to M or PR to PR count NOTHING for such change :) Could you modify your answer, please?

Comment: Stu Sztukowski - I think that I better describe this problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73811363/how-to-calculate-difference-between-dates-of-changes-in-2-columns-in-sas-enterpr

Comment: This should still ultimately get you the right answer. The running total is used to calculate the maximum difference. The final value at the end of the running total is what matters, not the values in-between. For example, by doing it this way, we're incrementally calculating the difference between 20MAY2020 and 15MAY2020 where the customer is set to P by adding the total number of days that they are P. Once they switch to PR, the counter resets back to 0. By selecting the max value of each running total, you'll get the right answer. If this does not, please post an example where it doesn't.

Comment: This has been edited based on the information in your other post. Please copy your updated question from your other post and delete it so people are answering in only one place.

Comment: Stu Sztukowski, I edited my post based on your tips. I suggest writing under this post. I modified question how code should run and present examples from my real data where it works bad. Furthermore, be aware, that as in example ID = 123 where it was 2 or more changes take max the number of days the customer lasted until returning to PR or how many days he is already on this shift if there was no return, can you modify your code, please ? :)

Comment: Stu Sztukowsi, could you check my edition of question and modify your code, please ?

Comment: The updated solution matches exactly what you've posted that you want. If you have additional issues for cases not addressed here then you'll have to modify the code to solve those specific cases.

Comment: Stu Sztukowski, I tested updated solution and it works perfectly, thank you very much for your time, discussion and you help, I gave you best answer! :)

Comment: @unbik You are very welcome. Your problem was a good challenge but also a great example of how powerful the Data Step is in SAS. I was happy to help. In the future, be sure to include all possible scenarios in your desired output. This will make solving your problem much faster.